# VBA Macro to change links in a seperate workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change links in a workbook, I have a different workbook in which the VBA code exists and its column A and B re with old and new links starting from 2nd row. But it's not working, and not giving any error as well.

I want to change links with a different workbook.

My code is below:

```vb
Sub UpdateLinks()
 
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim aLinks As Variant, vLink As Variant
    Dim rFoundLink As Range
    Dim rSrchRange As Range
    Dim MissingLinks As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    ' Open the workbook where the links are to be updated (target workbook)
    Dim targetWorkbookPath As Variant
    targetWorkbookPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", , "Select Workbook")
    
    ' Check if a file is selected
    If targetWorkbookPath <> False Then
        ' Open the selected workbook
        Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookPath)
        
        ' A list of your existing links that need updating checked by VBA.
        lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rSrchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
 
    
        ' Links that are in the target workbook
        aLinks = wbTarget.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
        
        If Not IsEmpty(aLinks) Then
            For Each vLink In aLinks
                Set rFoundLink = rSrchRange.Find(vLink, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False) ' Find the link in the list.
                If Not rFoundLink Is Nothing Then
                    ' If the link is found then update it to the link in the next column.
                    wbTarget.ChangeLink Name:=vLink, NewName:=rFoundLink.Offset(, 1), Type:=xlExcelLinks
                Else
                    ' If the link isn't found in the list then add it to a message string.
                    MissingLinks = MissingLinks & vLink & vbCr
                End If
            Next
        End If
    
        ' Any links that didn't update are displayed in a message.
        If MissingLinks <> "" Then
            MsgBox MissingLinks
        End If
        
        ' Save the target workbook
        wbTarget.Save
        
        ' Close the target workbook
        wbTarget.Close
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it mean exactly `not working`? Not change the link or the changed link not works as link, or something else:

Comment: Perhaps you want the `.hyperlinks` property of a `worksheet` rather than the `workbook.LinkSources`?

Comment: Hey, Actually if I want to run the code in the same workbook I can do that easily, But in this code the issue is that I am trying to run this code from a different workbook and I want to keep that as a different template to change the links in any of the template, In which old links are there in the column A and new links will be in the column B. When ni tried to go into step into mode I got to know that this code is not going into the below if condition

Comment: If Not rFoundLink Is Nothing Then
                ' If the link is found then update it to the link in the next column.
                wbTarget.ChangeLink Name:=vLink, NewName:=rFoundLink.Offset(, 1), Type:=xlExcelLinks
            Else